# Python wrapper causes redundant function calls

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, wrapper, urllib3

I have a function that downloads a file from a given url and, is called from a higher level function, i.e. `main()`.

```
from requests import get
...

def download_file(url):
    response = get(url)
    ...
    <error checks on response>
    ...
    # if no error, write response to file
    ...
    file.write(response)

def main(url):
    ...
    download_file(url)
```

However, I realized that I should place all the error checks for the `response` object outside the `download_file` function. So, I tried wrapping the `download_file` function so that all the error checks happen outside it.

```
def check_errors(func):
    def check_and_download(url):
        response = get(url)   
        ...
        <error checks on response>
        ...
        return func(url) # <- I have to call response = get(url) again. That's bad
    return check_and_download
```

As you can see, that wrapper causes the `response` to get called twice. Once outside the func, and once inside it. That's just redundant. I'm trying to figure out a way that will allow me to call `response` only **once** and download the file while having the error checks **outside** the `download_file` function.

I feel like this should be a common problem for beginners, but couldn't find relevant questions here. Any suggestions on how to properly deal with this?

**PS**: One approach I took was to modify the `download_file` function to accept a `response` object instead or a url, so that the wrapper could pass an error-checked response object to it. However, the problem then is that the `download_file` function must be called with a `response` object in `main()`. Which would require me to check the `response` object for errors in `main()` instead of the wrapper.

Comment: My design advice is: don't catch an exception just to raise another exception.  If you can't handle the error, then leaving the original exception and traceback intact is generally more useful.

Comment: @wim I know, I didn't do that in my actual code (wrote a comment). it's just for simplicity while explaining. i'll edit my snippet to remove the confusion

Comment: Then I think the MCVE is not good.  Whether you want to re-raise or handle error from `requests.get` is an important high-level question that shouldn't be glossed over.

Comment: @wim made `request.get` error checks more abstract